# Git lfs track all files under a subfolder

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am trying to track all files under a subfolder Assets/Large Assets, but the following is not working.
git lfs track "Assets/Large Assets/**"

Answer (score 3):

Using `git lfs track "Assets/Large Assets/**"` produces:

```
Assets/Large/[[:space:]]Assets/**
```

If you look closer you are getting "extra" `/` before `[[:space:]]` which breaks LFS filter.

Solution is to not use double quotes `"` and escape both `*` and escape spaces.

**End result would be:**

```
git lfs track Assets/Large\ Assets/\*\*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem, by renaming the subfolder to Large. For some reason subfolders don't work with spaces in the names.